# How come my custom Javascript code is working on one page of my Wordpress site but not on others?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

### Current Set Up

I am using **Wordpress** to create a doll artist site and for each doll I have created a custom `.php` template. For example, for the Cher doll I have created `cher.php`. Then in **wp admin** I have created a page called **cher** and in **Page Attributes > Template** I have selected **cher** as the template. So when I go to the page http://mitemiu.com/cher the **cher** doll template `cher.php` is loaded. That page works fine.

The `cher.php` calls the `header.php` first via the `get_header();` function. In the `header.php` function I link to `jquery-1.5.min.js`, `jquery.galleriffic.js` and `mitemiu.js`.

[Gallerific 2.0](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html) is a jQuery based gallery plug-in and `mitemiu.js` is my custom Javascript file which contains:

1. Gallerific custom settings *(image transition speed, UI components to be loaded, etc)*
2. Custom function called `toggleSlider()` for displaying/hiding of a doll selection menu
3. A statement to run `toggleSlider()` when the `a` element containing the title `doll` is clicked

---

**Relevant files** *(`jquery-1.5.min.js`, `jquery.galleriffic.js` remain pure & untouched by me)*

- `mitemiu.js` code http://pastebin.com/sBZg7vA2
- `header.php` http://pastebin.com/5ybzxBbM
- `cher.php` http://pastebin.com/tBE7f8YZ

---

### Problem

When you go to http://mitemiu.com/cher the page loads and works fine. When you click on the **dolls** link in the top navigation bar the `#doll-menu` DIV slides down/fades in via the `toggleSlider()` function. Click it again and the `#doll-menu` DIV fades out/slides up.

All is fine but, when you go to say any other page on the site *(blog, order, about, contact)* and then try clicking the **doll** link, BOOM! It doesn't work.

**How come the doll link only works on all doll pages and not on other pages?**

*Is there some sort of JS conflict occuring?*

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute of all the other links are right. However, the href attrubte of the doll page is "#", which just redirects to the top of the page.

So on all the doll pages, it seems right because it goes to the top of the doll page. But on all other pages, it just goes to the top of itself. On the other pages, just fix the href attribute of the doll link.

Comment: Yes the href of the doll link is "#" because clicking it is not supposed to take one anywhere. All clicking it should do is run the toggleSlider() function that slides down and fades in the #doll-menu DIV where one can click one of 6 doll links. When one of those 6 doll links are clicked, a new doll page is loaded. Besides, what would you have me change the doll link's href to?

Comment: He is trying to get the JS drop-down to work - not a simple HTML redirection.

Answer (score 0):

it is not working on other pages because in your `mitemiu.js` the first function assumes the existence of div id `thumbs` which does not exist outside of the dolls page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({ ...
```

It is not finding a div with id "`thumbs`" and the rest of the JS is not being loaded. If you remove this top function from the other pages it works just fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/FdqxS/

Or, if you don't want separate JS files, check for the div using:

```
if($('#thumbs').length > 0
```